# Can't import csv to neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

My code:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "C:\Users\Elmar\Desktop\tmp-raise.csv" AS line 
WITH line 
RETURN line
```

The error that it gives:
Invalid input ':': expected 'o/O' (line 1, column 18 (offset: 17))
"LOAD CSV FROM "C:\Users\Elmar\Desktop\tmp-raise.csv" AS line"
                  ^

I have also tried:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 
LOAD CSV FROM ""C:\Users\Elmar\Desktop\tmp-raise.csv" AS line
WITH line
RETURN line
```

What is the problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: too many double quotes, probably. remove the duplicate before your path.

Comment: could you please be more specific? beginner here. I deleted the duplicate file from comp tho if that's what you mean.

Comment: only one quotation mark before `C:\`

Comment: I noticed that, but it didn't work either. Same error:(

Comment: please edit your question with that typo fix and maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CSV import guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/), your path should be prefixed with `file:` and should use forward slashes. The example path given in the guide for windows is `file:c:/path/to/data.csv` (though I have seen example paths starting with `file://`). Give this a try:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:c:/Users/Elmar/Desktop/tmp-raise.csv' AS line
WITH line
RETURN line
```

If that doesn't work, give it a try with `file://` as the path prefix.

EDIT: Looks like CSV loads use a relative path from the default.graphdb/import folder. I had thought that was for Mac/Unix only, but it looks like Windows does the same. If you move CSVs you want to import into the import folder, you should be able to load them using `file:///theFileName.csv`

Comment: 'code' 'LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///Users/Elmar/Desktop/tmp-raise.csv' AS line
WITH line
RETURN line'
Tried this, and got "Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/Elmar/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/Users/Elmar/Desktop/tmp-raise.csv"

Comment: Tried what you suggested, got "URI is not hierarchical"

Comment: Looks like the windows version also starts looking relative to the default.graphdb/import/ folder. Try moving your csv there (C:/Users/Elmar/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/‌​), then use this for your path: `file:///tmp-raise.csv`

Comment: Tried that, got "Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/Elmar/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/tpm-raise.csv''. Also tried with USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000, got "Cannot use periodic commit in a non-updating query" :(

Comment: That path looks correct, is the csv file really at that location? Also, for the sake of this test, you will have to remove USING PERIOD COMMIT 10000 since your import isn't actually updating anything. You can add it back in after we can confirm that you can load a csv and you update your import to affect the graph.

Comment: Double-checked, it is at that location. I never thought I will stop for this long at first step:D any other suggestions?:)

Comment: Aside from checking for read permissions on the csv file, nothing comes to mind. If the file is actually in the import folder (you may have to create it, it wasn't there by default on my installation), and the path and file name are correct (from the error message it looks like it should be), I don't have any more to offer. Others on the site have more experience with imports and troubleshooting problems in this area, hopefully they have some insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
Load csv from "file:///C:/xyz.csv" as line
return line
```

The above code works well. But do comment out the configuration

```
dbms.directories.import=import
```

in the settings.

Other solution is you can drop a (.txt, .cyp, .cql) file in the drag to import box.